# Which one is official website for Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

my question is some one says learn bootstrap 4 while go to bootstrap website getbootstrap.com it shows bootstrap version 3.6.X some thing but when open this website v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com its shows bootstrap 4, so any one can tel me which one is official website?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will get a stable version of bootstrap from [`getbootstrap.com`](http://getbootstrap.com/), but you will get an alpha stage development version of the bootstrap from [`v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com`](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)

If you want to contribute in the development of the software, you can download it from `v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com` and if you just want to just do web development you can download it from `getbootstrap.com`

Answer (score 1):

http://getbootstrap.com/ this is the official website for Bootstrap.

The newer versions are usually first in Beta versions so that it could be tested and then it is launched for the public.
You need to select the stable version that has been recently launched.